# SQL Server - Case statement for one field based on content of other fields

Tags: sql-server, case

I have a query that brings back the following:

[image]

And want to bring back a 'Yes' for every client with a future booking.

[image]

It's relatively easy to bring back a 'Yes' for each booking in the the future using:

```
Case [DepartDate] 
When [Departdate] > getdate() then 'Yes' else 'no'
End AS 'Future booking?'
```

..but I'm stuck on how to bring back a yes against every client with future booking (regardless of the booking on the output line).

Can anyone help?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. You have the result of the second table using your example query? Are you looking for only Yes'?

Comment: What will be the [DepartDate] value for those clients ?

Comment: And what era do you leave in if 2007 is > getdate() ?

Comment: Hi, I don't have the results, above picture 2 is just an example of where I want to be.   If I were to use the Case above it would give me a 'yes' just against booking ID 207104.  I need a 'yes' against **all** bookings for clientID 777.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for a combination of the `CASE`, `MAX` and `OVER`

The following should get you the desired result:

```
SELECT  BookingID, 
        ClientID, 
        CASE 
            WHEN MAX(DepartDate) OVER(PARTITION BY ClientId) > GETDATE() THEN 'Yes'
            ELSE 'No'
        END AS [Future booking]
FROM    Bookings
```

Comment: This appears to be the simplest solution, without the need for extra joins on new select statements as suggested by others.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [BookingID]
      ,[ClientID]
      ,[DepartDate]
      ,CASE  
    When [DepartDate] > getdate() then 'Yes' else 'no'
    END as 'FutureDate?'
FROM [dbo].[Bookings]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pull in the future booking value from a separate query.

```
select booking_id, client_id, depart_date, 
   coalesce( (select distinct 'yes' 
              from booking future 
              where future.client_id = all_bookings.client_id 
              and future.depart_date > GETDATE() ), 'no') as future_booking
from booking all_bookings
```

Answer (score 0):

This will perform well especially if you have indexes on client_id and depart_date.

```
        select b.booking_id, 
        b.client_id, 
        b.depart_date, 
        case when future_booking.client_id is null then 'No' 
             else 'Yes' end as HasFuture
        from booking b
        left join   
           (select distinct client_id
                      from booking  
                      where depart_date > GETDATE() 
            ) as future_booking
        on b.client_id = future_booking.client_id
```